# Filter some rows from a matrix

Tags: matrix, filter, octave

Suppose I have this matrix:

```
matrix = [2 2; 2 3; 3 4; 4 5]
```

And now I'd like to filter out all rows which do not begin with an even number to produce

```
[2 2; 2 3; 4 5]
```

Is there a high-level procedure for doing this, or do I have to code for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a logical index for the rows whose first element is even, and use `:` to select all the columns. Here's how it's done, line by line:

```
octave> matrix = [2 2; 2 3; 3 4; 4 5]
matrix =

   2   2
   2   3
   3   4
   4   5

octave> ! mod (matrix(:,1), 2)
ans =

   1
   1
   0
   1

octave> matrix(! mod (matrix(:,1), 2),:)
ans =

   2   2
   2   3
   4   5
```

**EDIT:** in the comments below it was asked for other selection methods. I'm unaware of any specific function for it, but the thing above is indexing with a function:

```
even_rows = matrix(! mod (matrix(:,1), 2), :) # first element is even
s3_rows   = matrix(matrix(:,1) == 3, :); # first element is 3
int_rows  = matrix(fix (matrix(:,1)), == matrix(:,1), :); # first element is an integer
```

IF there was a function, one would still have to write the function, it wouldn't be any easier shorter or easier to read. But if you want to write a function, you could:

```
function selec = select_rows (func, mt)
  selec = mt(func (mt(:,1)),:);
endfunction
even_rows = select_rows (@(x) ! mod (x, 2), matrix);
se_rows   = select_rows (@(x) x == 3, matrix);
int_rows  = select_rows (@(x) fix (x) == x, matrix);
```

**EDIT2:** to have the rows that have already matched, simply keep track of them on the mask. Example:

```
mask = ! mod (matrix(:,1), 2); # mask for even numbers
even = matrix(mask,:);
mask = ! mask & matrix(:,1) == 3; # mask for left overs starting with a 3
s3   = matrix(mask,:);
rest = matrix(! mask, :); # get the leftovers
```

As above, you could write a function that does it. It would take a matrix as the first argument plus any number of function handles. It would iterate over the function handles modifying the mask everytime and filling a cell array with the matrices.

Comment: Thanks, I see now, would you happen to know if there's an easy way to partition the rows into several matrices? I hoped for it to be the same function.

Comment: @wvxvw can you be a bit more specific? Why do you want them split? And how? You mean you want groups of each row? I'm unsure of what you're asking.

Comment: Oh, I wanted that, say, given my example, there would be a function that given a predicate that classifies rows into several categories return matrices each containing rows belonging to that category. Say, I wanted that rows that have first element 2 would belong to first category, rows that belong to second category would have 3 as their first element and the rest would fall into third category. So that the function would return 3 matrices: `[2 2; 2 3], [3 4], [4 5]`

Comment: @wvxvw and what if a row matches more than one categories? I'd say to use my example above with different index. You could write a simple function that accepts a function handle to do it but that wouldn't save that much more typing.

Comment: The first predicate wins. Here's a prototype function (in Haskell it's a part of standard library API: http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=partition ), but OK, I see that that's probably something uncommon.

Comment: @wvxvw I have edited the question with examples on how to do it.

Comment: @wvxvw the first edit was in case you wanted for all matches. I have modified the question for picking only the first match.